# How to connect to WiFi using WPS PIN?

Tags: wireless-networking

my router Underneath is written "WPS PIN: 86395734" How do I connect to the router using only that PIN?

Comment: Don't use WPS PIN, it is a vulnerable protocol (easy to brute-force).  Connect to the router using a normal ethernet cable an configure WPA-PSK without the use of WPS.  If you must use WPS, disable the protocol after configuring WPA.

Comment: @grochmal I know, but...  How do I connect to the router using only that PIN?

Comment: @TheMasterKey501:  Consult your router manual or configuraton page to enable the option and it will be the first thing Windows will ask you when you try to connect to it.  As grochmal told you, it is a **very** bad idea to enable that but if you want to shoot yourself in the foot, go right ahead.

Answer (score -1):

There are two methods of using WPS - hardware and software.
First one means that you have to press special button on your router to initiate process-after button pressed  - you press another button on your 
wifi adapter(you need to have client adapter with hardware WPS support - physical WPS button ).
Second one means that you have to press button on the router and then connect with given WPS code  - via wifi (you need to know wifi SSID aka name).
Please remember that it is dangerous to use such unsecure  methods, you must disable WPS for security measures.

Answer (score -1):

Connecting to WPS pin will depend on what you are connecting with. Native Support for WPS PIN doens't exist in every device so you may not be able to use it.

For example, in windows 7 you select the ssid, then if it recognizes that your router is using the pin, you have the option to enter the WPS pin. If not, there are a variety of ways to do this.

Just google connectign to wps pin with *deviceName* where deviceName is the name of the computer/mobile device you are using.